# Como colocar el los a del navbar en horizontal?

Tags: css

Estoy haciendo un curso de freecodecamp y me ponen a hacer esta pagina de ejemplo: https://personal-portfolio.freecodecamp.rocks/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no logro hacer que el navbar quede igual, incluso he estado copiando todo el CSS desde el inspector de Chrome y aún nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé quedebe ser algo sencillo pero soy muy novato en esto y quiero aprender, intenté muchas cosas pero nada, no sé que hacer.

Mi código es éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

:root {
    --main-white: #f0f0f0;
    --main-red: #be3144;
    --main-blue: #45567d;
    --main-gray: #303841;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

head {
    display: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: var(--main-white);
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--main-red);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-white);
    padding: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

Intenté hacer un inline-block en el li, funciona pero se pone la barra muy pequeña y el texto igual.

Comment: Bueno. Pues yo obtuve el código fuente y el css y las imágenes del ejemplo en 2 minutos y me funciona muy bien

Comment: Si le agregaste más css, debes mostrar tu estilo y tú HTML también; no basta las imágenes

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Ya agregué una imagen del html

Comment: Por que tanta vuelta? Por que no descargar o copia el código siendo accesible y ya esta?

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz me dice que es mucho codigo para publicar

Comment: Si, pero no tanto también. Que parte querés y te ayudo. Solo el nav?

Comment: Si, solo el nav.

Comment: <!-- START NAV -->
    <nav id="navbar" class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAV -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es lo básico. A partir de aquí es necesario ir avanzado de a poco y probando parte por parte cada cosa que se vaya agregando, en la computadora y en modo movil (o en inspector del navegador) para asegurar también el response (como está en el original).

Tal como está, falta mucho por mejorar  pero esto es solo el nav.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
--main-white: #f0f0f0;
--main-red: #be3144;
--main-blue: #45567d;
--main-gray: #303841;
}

html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

html {
font-size: 62.5%;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.8rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.4;
color: var(--main-white);
paddin-top: 100px;
min-height: 1000px;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: var(--main-white);
padding: 20px;
}

.nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: var(--main-red);
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 0px;
z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
display: flex;
margin: 0 2rem;
}

.nav-list a {
display: block;
font-size: 2.2rem;
padding: 2rem;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}


main {
 width: 90%;
 height: 1000px;
 margin: 2rem auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" />

  </head>
  <body>

<nav id="navbar" class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>

<section class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hey I am Mimic</h1>
  <p>a web developer</p>
</section>

<section class="projects-section">
  <h2 class="projects-section-header">These are some of my projects</h2> 
</section>

</main>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Dave Tenés dos respuestas. Acepta con el ✓ el que más te convenga y te haya ayudado. Esto es para que quede cerrada tu pregunta y para que sirva a otros. Así funciona stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco si el código que compartes está completo pero con 2 líneas de css en `ul` se puede solucionar:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    :root {
    --main-white:#f0f0f0;
    --main-red:#be3144;
    --main-blue:#45567d;
    --main-gray:#303841;
    }

    body {
    font-family:Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size:1rem;
    color:var(--main-white);
    }

    .nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    width:100%;
    background:var(--main-red);
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0 2px 0;
    z-index:10;
    }

    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:var(--main-white);
    padding:20px;
    }

    ul {
    display:flex;
    list-style:none;
    padding:20px;
    }
```

```html
<nav id="navbar"class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#welcome-section"> About </a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Work </a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Funcionó, de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: El código es mejorable en muchos aspectos, me he limitado a lo que haz publicado, si estás aprendiendo, trata de jugar con los elementos, descubre lo que hacen y no desesperes.

Comment: ¿Algún consejo para desempeñarme mejor en esto? Ya perdí la cuenta de las veces que abandoné esto porque me quedé estancado en CSS.